# I want to add a space inbetween the group and team

Tags: javascript

So Leadership Team is how I want the end result

```
atGroupsDefaultColors: {
    LeadershipTeam: "rgba(255, 3, 3, 1)",
    DeveloperTeam: "rgba(230, 83, 0, 0.5)",
    ManagementTeam: "rgba(0, 255, 145, 0.5)",
    SnrAdmin: "rgba(11, 175, 255, 0.5)",
    Admin: "rgba(11, 175, 255, 0.5)",
    SnrModerator: "rgba(11, 175, 255, 0.5)",
    Moderator: "rgba(11, 175, 255, 0.5)",
    trialMod: "rgba(11, 175, 255, 0.5)",
},
staffTeamPage: {
    LeadershipTeam: [
```

Tried ChatGPT didn't come up with anything useful.